# How to get Windows 10 fonts to reset exactly as they were in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, fonts, themes

We are using a commercial application Eggplant to read text from C++ windows applications.

In order to do this, Eggplant accepts screenshots of labels that it can match on certain parts of the screen. This avoids us having to use their OCR library which is very sluggish and makes the tests take too long to finish.

So that is all fine and dandy. We have 1000's of these images that can be used to validate our windows application. And this has been working fine for some time now.

Now we had the test machines move from Windows 7 to Windows 10. And now all the tests are broken because the fonts are slightly different on Windows 10 than Windows 7.

Is there some way to completely revert all Windows 10 fonts to be exactly the same as the Windows 7 fonts? I still have access to the Windows 7 machines for some limited time. What would be a good set of steps to follow to get the fonts to appear exactly the same?

Comment: [Workflow](https://xkcd.com/1172/)

Comment: ha yeah. not an ideal spot to be in, but decisions from the past have been made and I have no control over them. :)

Comment: You could compare the files in `\Windows\Fonts` to find out which are actually different. It might help to copy `Windows 7` fonts to your `Windows 10` machine(s). Backup your fonts before you start. I am not aware of font changes. But [this discussion](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/13409-windows-7-font-rendering-better-than-windows-10-a.html) might have some insights for you.

Comment: Turns out my question was wrong. It is the theme causing my issues because the default background of a dialog box was changed from white to a grey color.

Comment: What makes you think its not your video driver, monitor, or something like that as they affect font display.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OPs issue was not caused by fonts but by dialog box background colour